# How can I create separate folders for Activity java classes and non-activity java classes in Android

Tags: java, android, class, package

A beginner here **:-)**

I have many Java classes in my *Java>>PackageName* folder. Some of them are activities and some are just normal classes that I've made to keep my java methods.

How can I create folders to categorize my java classes, like below..

**Activities folder-->** mainActivity.java, userActivity.java

**others-->** adapter.java, connection.java

**Thank You so much for your support..**

Comment: Use Java packages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply, i got it.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just starting out, you may want to read into this [beginner guide on Java packages](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/packages-in-java/)

Packages will become very important for portability and control access in your programs.